# How to avoid duplicated notifications from gnome MPlayer

Tags: lubuntu, notification

When I play music in Gnome Mplayer, at the time when song changes I can see two notifications with the next title of the song.

Can it be fixed to have only one song notification?

Comment: Please make a screenshot and add the link into your question

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a confirmed bug that I reported ashttps://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-mplayer/+bug/1434347

I don't currently know of any workarounds other than focusing the window when gnome-mplayer plays songs.